# Обработка пустых чекбоксов в php

Tags: php, html

Есть следующий html-код:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <div class="ingridients">
        <div class="ingridient">
            <input type="text" class="product_count" name="ing[]" placeholder="Название продукта">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="ing_to_product[]">Добавить одноименный продукт?</label>
        </div>

    </div>

    <p id="add_ing">Добавить ингредиент</p>
    <button name="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
<script src="/template/js/libs.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#add_ing').click(function(){
        $('.ingridients').append("<div class='ingridient'><input type='text' class='product_count' name='ing[]' placeholder='Название продукта'><label><input type='checkbox' name='ing_to_product[]'>Добавить одноименный продукт?</label></div>");
    });
</script>
```

По клику на "добавить ингредиент" добавляет еще один div ingridient. Нужно отслеживать чекбокс у каждого ингредиента, т.е. если не отмечен - передаем 0, если отмечен - передаем 1. Как правильно это сделать?
PHP код обработчика:

```
$ingridients = $_POST['ing'];
$ing_to_product = $_POST['ing_to_product'];

for ($i=0; $i < count($ingridients); $i++) { 
  $ing[$i]['ingridient'] = $ingridients[$i];
  $ing[$i]['to_product'] = $ing_to_product[$i];
}
```

Пока что он только склеивает эти 2 массива, но пустое значение checkbox не передается. Видел подобие решения со скрытым input'ом, который передает 0, если чекбокс неактивен. Кто знает решение этой проблемы?

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас не могу вспомнить точно, как это реализовавыл, но, точно помню, что я отслеживал активность check-box. Было примерно так:

```
if (isset($_POST['ing_to_product[]'])) 
   foreach($_POST['ing_to_product[]'] as $key=>$value) 
      echo $value.'<BR>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю так получится:

```
<div class="ingridients">
        <div class="ingridient">
            <input type="text" class="product_count" name="ing[]" placeholder="Название продукта">
            <input type="hidden" name="ing_to_product[]" value="0">
            <label><input type="checkbox" onchange="$(this).parents('.ingridient').find('input[name^=ing_to_product]').val($(this).is(':checked')?1:0)">Добавить одноименный продукт?</label>
        </div>

</div>
```